# Convertir los datos de excel en un json para verlo en una datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, excel, datatables

Quiero pasar los datos que contiene un archivo Excel a un json, esto ya lo realizo con un algortimo que encontre en internet ahora quiero pasar ese json a un datatable, pero no se como hacerlo, no logro hacerlo. con la investigación que realice encontré como leer un archivo Excel desde javascript y convertirlo a json, e igualmente cree el datatable, el json se muestra correctamente al hacer un console.log, pero no se como llamarlo al inicialziar el datatable

Lo que llevo hasta ahora es:

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input class="form-control" type="file" id="input" accept=".xls,.xlsx">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="button">Convert</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <pre id="jsondata"></pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <table id="control" class="display" style="width:100%">

    </table>
</div>
```

Archivo js para cargar el datatable

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#control').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: 'app.js',
        dataSrc: ''
    },
    language: {
        url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Spanish.json'
    }, 

    columns: [
        {
            title: 'Orden de Producción',
            data: "ORDEN DE PRODUCCIÓN",
        },
        {
            title: 'Cod producto',
            data: 'COD PRODUCTO',
        },
        {
            title: 'Linea',
            data: 'LINEA', 
        },
        {
            title: 'Unidades a Producir',
            data: 'UND A PRODUCIR',
        },
        {
            title: 'Unidades a Entregar',
            data: 'UND ENTREGADAS', 
        },
        {
            title: 'Avance',
            data: 'AVANCE', 
        },
        {
            title: 'Estado',
            data: 'ESTADO', 
        },
    ]
});
```

});

archivo js para convertir Excel a json

```
 let selectedFile;
 console.log(window.XLSX);
 document.getElementById('input').addEventListener("change", (event) => {
 selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
 })

 let data=[{
  "name":"jayanth",
  "data":"scd",
  "abc":"sdef"
  }]


 document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", () => {
 XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data, 'out.xlsx');
  if(selectedFile){
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);
    fileReader.onload = (event)=>{
     let data = event.target.result;
     let workbook = XLSX.read(data,{type:"binary"});
     console.log(workbook);
     workbook.SheetNames.forEach(sheet => {
          let rowObject = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheet]);
          data = rowObject;
          console.log(rowObject);
          document.getElementById("jsondata").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(rowObject,undefined,4)
     });
    }
   }
  });
```

JSON
[
{
"ORDEN DE PRODUCCIÓN": "005-19",
"COD PRODUCTO": 20001,
"LINEA": "SOLIDOS",
"TQ A PRODUCIR": 10,
"UND ENTREGADAS": 8,
"% AVANCE": 0.8,
"ESTADO": "EN PROCESO"
},
{
"ORDEN DE PRODUCCIÓN": "005-20",
"COD PRODUCTO": 20002,
"LINEA": "LIQUIDO",
"TQ A PRODUCIR": 6,
"UND ENTREGADAS": 0,
"% AVANCE": 0,
"ESTADO": "PROGRAMADO"
},
{
"ORDEN DE PRODUCCIÓN": "005-21",
"COD PRODUCTO": 20002,
"LINEA": "LIQUIDO",
"TQ A PRODUCIR": 6,
"UND ENTREGADAS": 0,
"% AVANCE": 0,
"ESTADO": "APLAZADO"
},
{
"ORDEN DE PRODUCCIÓN": "006-20",
"COD PRODUCTO": 20003,
"LINEA": "SEMISOLIDO",
"TQ A PRODUCIR": 2,
"UND ENTREGADAS": 2,
"% AVANCE": 1,
"ESTADO": "TERMINADO"
}
]

Comment: como queda tu objeto una vez que realizas sheet_to_row_object_array

Comment: Hola, ya lo subi, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si lo único que requieres es pasar los datos a un Datatable, y tu ya tienes definido tu datatable, lo único que tienes que hacer es asignar el datatable a una variable cuando la inicializas.

```
var table = $("#control").DataTable({
```

Cuando tengas tus datos de el Excel en tu json, pasarlos con la función, `table.rows.add()`.

Única observación tienes que validar que los campos en que definas en tu datatables existan para que no te genere un error al pintarla.
En este caso yo moví dos, por que esta diferente el nombre de tu json y de la columna que defines.

te dejo el ejemplo de como quedara.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var table = $("#control").DataTable({
    language: {
      url: "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Spanish.json"
    },
    columns: [
      {
        title: "Orden de Producción",
        data: "ORDEN DE PRODUCCIÓN"
      },
      {
        title: "Cod producto",
        data: "COD PRODUCTO"
      },
      {
        title: "Linea",
        data: "LINEA"
      },
      {// Lo moví ya que lo tenias como "UND A PRODUCIR"
        title: "Unidades a Producir",
        data: "TQ A PRODUCIR"
      },
      {
        title: "Unidades a Entregar",
        data: "UND ENTREGADAS"
      },
      {// Lo moví ya que lo tenias como "AVANCE"
        title: "Avance",
        data: "% AVANCE"
      },
      {
        title: "Estado",
        data: "ESTADO"
      }
    ]
  });

  var datos = [
    {
      "ORDEN DE PRODUCCIÓN": "005-19",
      "COD PRODUCTO": 20001,
      LINEA: "SOLIDOS",
      "TQ A PRODUCIR": 10,
      "UND ENTREGADAS": 8,
      "% AVANCE": 0.8,
      ESTADO: "EN PROCESO"
    },
    {
      "ORDEN DE PRODUCCIÓN": "005-20",
      "COD PRODUCTO": 20002,
      LINEA: "LIQUIDO",
      "TQ A PRODUCIR": 6,
      "UND ENTREGADAS": 0,
      "% AVANCE": 0,
      ESTADO: "PROGRAMADO"
    },
    {
      "ORDEN DE PRODUCCIÓN": "005-21",
      "COD PRODUCTO": 20002,
      LINEA: "LIQUIDO",
      "TQ A PRODUCIR": 6,
      "UND ENTREGADAS": 0,
      "% AVANCE": 0,
      ESTADO: "APLAZADO"
    },
    {
      "ORDEN DE PRODUCCIÓN": "006-20",
      "COD PRODUCTO": 20003,
      LINEA: "SEMISOLIDO",
      "TQ A PRODUCIR": 2,
      "UND ENTREGADAS": 2,
      "% AVANCE": 1,
      ESTADO: "TERMINADO"
    }
  ];

  setTimeout(() => {
    table.rows.add(datos).draw();
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
    />

    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.22/datatables.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <input
            class="form-control"
            type="file"
            id="input"
            accept=".xls,.xlsx"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" id="button">Convert</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <pre id="jsondata"></pre>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="control" class="display" style="width: 100%;"></table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```